# Why do java processes continue to run after I terminate in the console?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, command-prompt

Just a note: I am using a MacBook Pro with Yosemite and an i5 processor. 
Anyways, I often notice that after I close a java application through the console that the process associated with the last runtime for that application is still running on the cpu.

For example:
I run a java application programmed through eclipse through the console. 
I terminate the application through eclipse through the console.
6 hours later, I check under my Activity Monitor, and I see that the same java process that I terminated earlier has been running on the cpu for the past 6 hours, which adds a considerable amount to the cpu load.

Why does the java process still continue to run after I terminate it through the console?

**Addressing the comments:**
I am launching and terminating through/inside eclipse through the console as mentioned above. 
Also, I am closing it using the red terminate button on the console window, which changes to grey when pressed.

Comment: are you launching it in the Eclipse console? or something else? Typically when you terminate it the process dies, so if it's still running then you're not actually terminating it...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I terminate the application through eclipse through the console."? If you are starting it in the console outside of eclipse, closing it in eclipse won't do anything. It doesn't matter that you coded it with eclipse or not, it would only matter how you're running it.

Comment: I sincerely hope you are not closing the Eclipse console window to terminate it. Use the red square button at the top with tooltip "Stop" :)